# Patch a dataclass attribute which is dynamically generated in its dependency in unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I am new to Unit testing. I have used mocking, patching in the past but the case I have is a little bit complicated for me to create unit tests.

So I have a file: `parent.py` with the following data class

```
import multiprocessing
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ParentClass:
    cpu_count: int = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

I have another module `child.py` with the following data class

```
from stackoverflow.parent import ParentClass
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
      some_attribute_1: int = 1
      some_attribute_2: int = 2
      ....
```

Finally, I have a third module `actual_function.py` that uses these data classes.

```
from stack_overflow.child import ChildClass


def get_cpu_count_and_attributes(cc: ChildClass):
    return cc.cpu_count, cc.some_attribute_1
```

Here, I want to unit test `print_cpu_count_and_attributes` function. How does patching work here? I created the following test case and it fails. The cpu_count in my system is 16 but I want to mock it with return value 8 so that it works on other machines with different number of cores

```
from unittest import mock
from stack_overflow.actual_function import *
from stack_overflow.child import ChildClass


@mock.patch('stack_overflow.parent.multiprocessing.cpu_count', return_value=8)
def test_print_cpu_count_and_attributes():
    cc = ChildClass()
    assert get_cpu_count_and_attributes(cc) == (8, 1)
```

Here is the folder structure.

```
stackoverflow
├── __init__.py
  ├── actual_function.py
  ├── child.py
  ├── parent.py
  └── test_function.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to test `ChildClass`, you should path it, not the parent in different module.

Heuristincs with mocking:

1. Patch what you test
2. Patch as close to target function as possible

The reason why patch in your case isn't working is that python will not re-evaluate modules & class hierarchy after patch. And as python is dynamic, what's happening is

1. Parent class evaluated
2. Child class evaluated with reference to parent class object
3. You patch parent class in parent module, but testing code in `actual_function`, and `ChildClass` there is referencing old original `Parent`, because `mock` is actually changing object attributes of `Parent` in `parent.py` namespace.

Also, take a look at [mock documentation on patching point](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

---

Example for your case:

```
with mock.patch.object(ChildClass, 'cpu_count', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as m:
    m.return_value = 42
    get_cpu_count_and_attributes(ChildClass())
```

You should not change *inherited* attributes/properties, you should put patches *on top* of target (hence the name ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It makes sense to patch `ChildClass` as you mentioned. However, I just want to patch the specific attribute(cpu_count) of the parent data class that `ChildClass` is inheriting from. That is where it gets tricky. If I mock entire dataclass, I will have to set values for other attributes too, which I want to avoid

Comment: @Manoj I've updated answer with example for your case